# Mapping into the Hilbert cube - where is compactness needed?

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

I am not sure why $X$ is assumed to be compact in the Lemma below.

It seems to me that the proof would work fine if $X$ is any metric space (with metric $\varrho$).

Am I correct?

[image]

[image]

By the way $|g-f|$ is defined to be $\sup\{|g(x)-f(x)|:x\in X\}$, and $\mathscr I=[0,1]$, and $\aleph_0=\omega$.

Comment: Where $|f(x)|=\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n}|f^n(x)|$ for $f(x)=\langle f^n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$. (Actually, $\aleph_0=\Bbb Z^+$ here.) It seems to work in general. I don’t see any place where compactness of $X$ is used; $|f(x)|$ is bounded by $1$, so there’s no problem with the supremum. (What’s this from? The notation looks like early 20th century.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, thanks.

It's from a Topology book by Kuratowski.  I think it's from the 1960's.

Comment: 1966, so far as I can tell, translating the French edition of 1958. The ReadInside at Amazon showed enough that I can see that he did at least mention the modern notation $\{x:\varphi(x)\}$ in a footnote, but his notation certainly is conservative.